# how to enter the user's reply message on the bot and put it in a variable

Tags: python, variables, bots, py-telegram-bot-api

so the problem here is I want to enter data into the database via a bot, and I'm trying to retrieve word for word with arrays or indexing, but what if the user wants to enter data into the name column and has a varied name which can consist of 4-3 sentences, so do you guys have a solution [My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me9th.png)

I'm confused, I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that class and status are always a single word so take texts[-1] as status, texts[-2] as class and texts[:-2] as the name. This way if it is a name with 3-4 words then all of it will be accounted for.